# C# - Asp Button doesn't properly trigger event in C# file

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net, button

I'm having a problem with my website. I'm trying to make a simple user registration form but the asp:Button that I'm using to trigger the form send off doesn't seem to be working. When the form is completed and the button is clicked, nothing happens. But if the form is incomplete (for example, two passwords don't match) then the event does fire. I think it has something to do with the image field and one of its validation checks but I've deliberated over it for ages to no avail. I'll post the code for the form, and the full C# file and hopefully someone can point out where I'm going wrong!

HTML:

```
 <form runat="server">

    <asp:updatepanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel1" updatemode="Conditional">

                            <ContentTemplate>

                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" CssClass="info" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false"></asp:Label>

                                <asp:ScriptManager EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>





                                <div class="col-md-6 animated bounceIn center-block">
                                    <h2 class="text-center animated fadeIn wow" data-wow-delay="0.2s">Your Details</h2>
                                    <hr class="light animated fadeIn wow" data-wow-delay="0.4s"> 
                                    <div class="col-md-12 animated bounceIn wow" data-wow-delay="0.6s">
                                        <div class="row form-group">
                                            <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
                                                <p class="text-default bounceIn text-center">Forename: </p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">

                                                <p>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </p>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="fa fa-2x fa-exclamation-triangle animated bounceIn" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="row form-group">
                                            <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
                                                <p class="text-default bounceIn text-center">Surname: </p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">

                                                <p>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </p>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="fa fa-2x fa-exclamation-triangle animated bounceIn" Visible="false"></asp:Label>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row form-group">
                                            <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
                                                <p class="text-default bounceIn text-center">Email: </p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">

                                                <p>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" TextMode="Email"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </p>


                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="fa fa-2x fa-exclamation-triangle animated bounceIn" Visible="false"></asp:Label>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row form-group">
                                            <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
                                                <p class="text-default bounceIn text-center">Confirm Email: </p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">

                                                <p>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" CssClass="fa fa-2x fa-exclamation-triangle animated bounceIn" Visible="false"></asp:Label>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="row form-group">
                                            <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
                                                <p class="text-default bounceIn text-center">City: </p>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <p>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="fa fa-2x fa-exclamation-triangle animated bounceIn" Visible="false"></asp:Label>

                                            </div>



                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <!--Section for account details-->
                                <div class="col-md-6 animated bounceIn center-block">
                                    <h2 class="text-left animated fadeIn wow text-center" data-wow-delay="1.2s">Account Details</h2>
                                    <hr class="light animated fadeIn wow" data-wow-delay="1.4s"/>
                                    <div class="col-md-12 animated bounceIn wow" data-wow-delay="1.6s">
                                        <div class="row form-group">
                                            <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
                                                <p class="text-default bounceIn text-center">Username: </p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">

                                                <p>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </p>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="fa fa-2x fa-exclamation-triangle animated bounceIn" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>




                                        <div class="row form-group">
                                            <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
                                                <p class="text-default bounceIn text-center">Password: </p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">

                                                <p>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </p>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="fa fa-2x fa-exclamation-triangle animated bounceIn wow" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="row form-group">
                                            <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
                                                <p class="text-default bounceIn text-center">Confirm Password: </p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">

                                                <p>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </p>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="fa fa-2x fa-exclamation-triangle animated bounceIn" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="row form-group">
                                            <div class="col-sm-2 text-right">
                                                <p class="text-default bounceIn text-center">Profile Picture: </p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="fa fa-2x fa-exclamation-triangle animated bounceIn" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                            </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>


                                </div>

                                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Register" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-xl center-block fa-2x flipInX wow" data-wow-delay="2.0s" OnClick="registerbutton_Click" />

                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:updatepanel>

</form>
```

C#:

```
public partial class register : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected string incompleteField = "";
    protected Boolean complete = false;
    protected Boolean imgOk = true;
    Boolean userExists = false;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        resetWarnings();

    }


    protected void registerbutton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkFields();
        checkFields();
        checkUsername();

        if (complete == false)
        {
            statusLabel.Text = incompleteField + " field is empty. Please ensure all fields of the form are complete and try again";
            statusLabel.Visible = true;
            incompleteField = "";

            register_form.Update();
        }
        //if the username is already taken
        else if (userExists == true)
        {
            statusLabel.Text = "An account already exists with that username. Please enter another one";
            statusLabel.Visible = true;
            userwarning.Visible = true;


            register_form.Update();
        }
        else if (imgOk == false)
        {
            register_form.Update();
        }
        else if (emailtext.Text != confirmemailtext.Text)
        {
            statusLabel.Text = "Email addresses provided do not match. Please try again.";
            statusLabel.Visible = true;
            emailtext.Text = ""; emailwarning.Visible = true;
            confirmemailtext.Text = ""; confirmemailwarning.Visible = true;

            register_form.Update();
        }
        else if (passtext.Text != confirmpasstext.Text)

        {
            statusLabel.Text = "Passwords do not match. Please try again";
            statusLabel.Visible = true;
            passtext.Text = ""; passwarning.Visible = true;
            confirmpasstext.Text = ""; confirmpasswarning.Visible = true;
        }


        else
        {

            string forename = forenametext.Text;
            string surname = surnametext.Text;
            string location = locationtext.Text;
            string email = emailtext.Text;
            string uname = usertext.Text;
            string pword = passtext.Text;


            string imgName = "";
            string imgPath = "";

            if (profileimgupload.HasFile == true)
            {
                Random r = new Random();
                int rint = r.Next(0, 10000);
                imgName = profileimgupload.FileName;
                imgPath = "/userImg/" + rint + imgName;
                profileimgupload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(imgPath));
            }
            else
            {
                imgName = null;
                imgPath = null;
            }



            string connectionstring = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["elmtreeconnect"].ConnectionString;

            SqlConnection myconnection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

            myconnection.Open();

            string query = "INSERT INTO users (forename, surname, location, email, username, password, accountType, imgPath) VALUES(@forename, @surname, @location, @email, @username, @password, @accounttype, @imgpath)";

            SqlCommand register = new SqlCommand(query, myconnection);

            register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@forename", forename);
            register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", surname);
            register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
            register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", location);
            register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", uname);
            register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", pword);
            register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accounttype", "user");
            register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imgpath", imgName);

            register.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Session["register"] = "true";

            myconnection.Close();
            Response.Redirect("registersuccess.aspx");
        }
    }

    protected void checkFields()
    {

        complete = false;


        if (forenametext.Text == "")
        {
            forenamewarning.Visible = true;
            incompleteField = "Forename";

            return;
        }
        else if (surnametext.Text == "")
        {
            surnamewarning.Visible = true;
            incompleteField = "Surname";

            return;

        }
        else if (emailtext.Text == "")
        {
            emailwarning.Visible = true;
            incompleteField = "Email";

            return;
        }
        else if (confirmemailtext.Text == "")
        {
            confirmemailwarning.Visible = true;
            incompleteField = "Confirm Email";

            return;
        }
        else if (locationtext.Text == "")
        {
            locationwarning.Visible = true;
            incompleteField = "City";

            return;
        }

        else if (usertext.Text == "")
        {
            userwarning.Visible = true;
            incompleteField = "Username";

            return;
        }
        else if (passtext.Text == "")
        {
            passwarning.Visible = true;
            incompleteField = "Password";

            return;
        }
        else if (confirmpasstext == null)
        {
            confirmpasswarning.Visible = true;
            incompleteField = "Confirm Password";

            return;
        }

        else
        {
            complete = true;
        }

    }

    protected void checkImage()
    {
        String upPath = Server.MapPath("~/userImg");
        if (profileimgupload.FileName != null)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(upPath) == false)
            {
                statusLabel.Text = "ERROR: File Directory " + upPath + " does not exist. Please try again. If the problem persists, contact support at info@elmtree.co.uk";
                profileimgwarning.Visible = true;
                incompleteField = "Profile Picture";
                imgOk = false;

            }
            else if (Directory.Exists(upPath) == true)
            {
                if (profileimgupload.PostedFile.ContentLength > 1000000)
                {
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "Alert", "Alert,('Image file is too large. Unable to upload.')");
                    statusLabel.Text = "The image you have chosen is too big. Please use an image with a smaller filesize.";
                    profileimgwarning.Visible = true;
                    profileimgupload.Attributes.Clear();
                    imgOk = false;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //method used to remove warnings on page
    protected void resetWarnings()
    {
        forenamewarning.Visible = false;
        surnamewarning.Visible = false;
        emailwarning.Visible = false;
        confirmemailwarning.Visible = false;
        locationwarning.Visible = false;
        passwarning.Visible = false;
        confirmpasswarning.Visible = false;
        userwarning.Visible = false;
        profileimgwarning.Visible = false;
        statusLabel.Text = "";

    }

    protected void checkUsername()
    {
        string connectionstring = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["elmtreeconnect"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection myconnection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

        myconnection.Open();
        string newUser = usertext.Text;
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = @user";
        SqlCommand searchUsernames = new SqlCommand(query, myconnection);
        searchUsernames.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", newUser);
        SqlDataReader rdr = searchUsernames.ExecuteReader();
        if (rdr.HasRows)
        {
            userExists = true;
        }

    rdr.Close();
    myconnection.Close();

}
```

Comment: Putting the ScriptManager inside an UpdatePanel is a bit odd and seems like it would screw up the AJAX-like updating of the panel...try putting the ScriptManager outside?

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm studying at university and still learning the good, bad and ugly of HTML. Tried moving it outside, and it didn't make any difference.